# OCIO Profile Error

Tags: color, performance, startup-file

I am having a problem with OCIO profile. In version 3.5.1 I installed AGx OCIO but then I uninstalled it because it didn't have a good integration with the addons. After uninstalling and deleting everything related to that version of blender still persists that error despite using colorgmanagment that comes with blender the filmic. The same thing happens when I export a model to substance painter to texture a model, it forces me to change OCIO.[image]